# The constructor is undefined. (Working with an Array here)

Tags: php, arrays, object, constructor, compiler-errors

So the goal of my school assignment is to print the elements of the Array through a constructor that is in my Dwarves class.

The array should contain objects, and each of those objects should have their own name.

But when I try to create an object in the main, the object wants me to put a string value in the default constructor of the object... so how can I print my Array data with a constructor in the main?
For my Dwarves class.

```
package prac11;

public class Dwarves {
Dwarves[] speler;{
    speler = new Dwarves[8];    
}
public String name;

Dwarves(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void generate() {
    
    speler[0] = new Dwarves("Muir");
    speler[1] = new Dwarves("Buith");
    speler[2] = new Dwarves("Gort");
    speler[3] = new Dwarves("Coll");
    speler[4] = new Dwarves("Duir");
    speler[5] = new Dwarves("Quert");
    speler[6] = new Dwarves("Nion");
    speler[7] = new Dwarves("Gus");
    
//  name[0] = "Muir";
//  name[1] = "Buith";
//  name[2] = "Gort";
//  name[3] = "Coll";
//  name[4] = "Duir";
//  name[5] = "Quert";
//  name[6] = "Nion";
//  name[7] = "Gus";

    
}
public void identify() {
    for (int i = 0; i < speler.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("I am " + speler[i]);
    }
}
public void killDwarf(String name) {
    
}

}
```

For my main

```
package prac11;

public class SnowWhite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Dwarves figure = new Dwarves();
        figure.generate();
        figure.identify();
    }

}
```

edit: didn't know how to embed code. :)
Code is written in Java.

Comment: please include the code don't use screenshots. it makes it tedious for potential answerers to hae to retype your code in order to help you... read [ask]

Comment: i'm wondering wich version of PHP is that. initialize the parameter with default value or pass one into the construktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks more like java.

You have a single class trying to accommodate a single dwarf and a dwarf collection. This is not working.

The class should be `Dwarf()` which represents a single dwarf. For this, the constructor is correct; it accepts the name of the dwarf.

The `generate()` function should be outside the class. This function will create the collection of dwarf instances. You can create a new class for this, but java already has several collection classes you can use.

Comment: So it kind of work right now, for the object part.
But for the output i get this:

I am prac11.Dwarves@7852e922
I am prac11.Dwarves@4e25154f
I am prac11.Dwarves@70dea4e
I am prac11.Dwarves@5c647e05
I am prac11.Dwarves@33909752
I am prac11.Dwarves@55f96302
I am prac11.Dwarves@3d4eac69
I am prac11.Dwarves@42a57993

Comment: You're printing the class names. You should print the dwarf name: `System.out.println("I am " + speler[i].name);`

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)